# How Can I Change The Color Of Polyline Back to The Previous One On Click Google Api V2 C# Web App?

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-2, polyline

I am easily changing the color of polyline on click button my code below,

```
 var points = [  
     new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),  
     new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958)];
 var polyline = new GPolyline(points, '#ff0000', 5, 0.7); 

 GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: "#0000FF" }); });
map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

but I want to change its color back to previous one on click such that if its initial color is red and on click it changes to blue then on other click it changes it to red again ... . then what should I do ?

Hopes for your reply..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many solutions for this. one is to create a swap function:

```
 var activeColor = '#ff0000';
 var inactiveColor = '#0000FF';

 var points = [   
                                   new GLatLng(24.85229, 67.01703),   
                                   new GLatLng(24.914463, 67.0965958)]; 
                                   var polyline = new GPolyline(points, activeColor, 5, 0.7);  

GEvent.addListener(polyline, "click", function() {
           // swap activecolor with inactivecolor
           var color = inactiveColor;
           inactiveColor = activeColor;
           activeColor = color;

           // set activecolor
           polyline.setStrokeStyle({ color: activeColor }); 
       }); 
       map.addOverlay(polyline);
```

Comment: polite i am also trying to change the marker color on post back the same marker in between which the polyline created .. . is there any solution for that ?